# windows xp error, restarts on enabling LAN connection

Tags: windows-xp, lan, reboot, bsod

Sometimes when I enable my LAN connection then the System restarts with a blue screen showing "A problem has occurred" and processes something.

Then, Windows restarts properly, but a message appears:

> Windows has recovered from a serious problem

with details as follows:

```
BCCode : 100000c5     BCP1 : 0000000B     BCP2 : 00000002     BCP3 : 00000000
BCP4 : 8054B0BA     OSVer : 5_1_2600     SP : 3_0     Product : 256_1     

C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER9641.dir00\Mini050711-01.dmp
C:\DOCUME~1\ADMINI~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER9641.dir00\sysdata.xml
```

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Does it work when you boot into safe mode? Could be because of the drivers. You can inspect the .dmp file generated: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315263

Comment: @slhck: sir, my system works properly, there's no problem. this error occurs sometimes. and when the system restarts , there's no problem

Comment: when i enable the LAN connection , then it restarts, a blue screen also appears, and windows boots without any problem, and them am again on the working mode. i mean my windows remains in working condition.

Comment: What I mean is, does the error occur also in safe mode? But anyway, the .dmp file will give you hints to the problem itself